# how to use localstorage for login using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I'd written a code for login using javascript

```
function checkLogin()
{
    if(localStorage.login=="true")
    {
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    }
    else if(localStorage.login=="false")
    {
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    }
}
```

where localStorage.login="true" & "false" has been assigned from server dynamically

The page get looply redirected when i  include this code!!

Give me solutions for :

How to remove / destroy user defined function after execution ?

or

How to execute user defined function for **only one time ondeviceready** in jquery

Comment: *localStorage.login="true" & "false" has been assigned from server dynamically*. It's not possible to set localStorage from server. Need more details here about how you set this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to call this function from only the pages you want to redirect to the login and, as Emad Melad says, outside the `login.html` page.

If what you want is that people that go again to login.php page get redirected to index.php if they're logged in, you could try to detect which page you are in, and make an `IF` so if it's the login page it's not executed. It would be something like this:

```
function checkLogin()
{
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1)

    if(localStorage.login=="true")
    {
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    }
    else if(localStorage.login=="false" && filename != 'login.html')
    {
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    }
}
```

[* The snippet code to get the actual URL](http://befused.com/javascript/get-filename-url)

However, from what I read in your code, you will be redirected the same to `index.html` from everypage that calls this function.

Usually, what I do in my apps is to check only if it's not logged in, and redirect to `login.html` if it's the case. What I'd do, modifying a little bit your function, is:

```
    function checkLogin()
    {
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1)

        if(localStorage.login=="true" && filename == 'login.html')
        {
            window.location.href = "index.html";
        }
        else if(localStorage.login=="false" && filename != 'login.html')
        {
            window.location.href = "login.html";
        }
    }
```

That way, you will be only redirected to `index.html` if you are logged in and you are in login.php, and the other way you will be only redirected to `login.html` everywhere if you are not logged in, except for `login.html`.

Hope it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set LocalStorage from server. LocalStorage located in client browser. 
I guess your code is looping because you call your checkLogin() function once loginpage is loaded. and because the localStorage is empty. 
this line of code will execute

```
window.location.href = "login.html";
```

and the page loaded again and check again for localStorage and it's empty

To fix this. 
you should call your function outside the login page.

Answer (score -1):

To **set** localStorage object:

```
localStorage.setItem('objName','objValue');
```

To **get** localStorage object:

```
localStorage.getItem('objName');
```